# Why do astronauts wear heels?

Tags: spacesuits, eva

I was reading [another question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/2586/13761) on the site when I noticed the EVA suit sports heels.

[image: Astronaut with heels]

Why do they put heels on space suits?  ([cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuIQh.png) detailed view)

Comment: Sometimes they walk in the spacesuit also in gravity? For example, if they enter the spaceship before launch.

Comment: Different suits are worn for launch and landing.

Comment: Frankly, from the title, I was hoping you would be asking about this picture https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DSJpX2tWkAA68sd.jpg

Comment: To help the shorter astronauts feel better ?     :-P

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That only *looks* like a heel!  As shown here, it's a "foot restraint interface"!

That said, it probably makes walking around in the training facilities a lot easier.  Although that doesn't happen much - the EMUs are *heavy*.

[image]

Source: [JSC-19450
Rev. B
Extravehicular Mobility Unit
Systems Training Workbook](https://archive.org/details/EMUSystemsWorkbookJSC19450B/mode/2up)

This picture of a Manipulator Foot Restraint - it was grappled by the shuttle robot arm and used to move crewpersons around - shows the interface with the boot.  You can see where the heels fit.

[image]

Source: [Smithsonian Air & Space museum](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/manipulator-foot-restraint-and-grapple-fixture-shuttle-hubble-space-telescope)

And here's a crewperson in the restraint.

[image]

[Source](https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/162457main_rms04_S84-27040_hires.jpg)

Finally, here's the Portable Foot Restraint attached to the space station robot arm. You can see it has the same interface to the boot.

[image]

[Source](https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/ob4Z6Pm/videoblocks-astronaut-spacewalk-riding-robotic-arm-orbiting-earth-animation-4k-some-elements-furnished-by-nasa-images_rrtb_ntxw_thumbnail-full01.png)

Comment: Is it still in use on the ISS, or is it a legacy thing ?

Comment: Yes. The ISS suit is essentially the same as the shuttle suit. The bottom picture shows the space station robot arm.  I will edit the answer to make that clear, thanks.

Comment: Basically it is a cleat, like on a downhill ski boot.

Comment: I hope there is an additional safety ine beyond that boot attachment.

Comment: Tether protocols are strictly followed. In the bottom picture you can see the tether attached near the foot restraint mount and stretching up to the crewperson.

Comment: Awesome, I always assumed they held magnets in those heels.

Comment: Of course, if you go back as far as Persian Cavalry "foot restraint interface" and "heel" are the same thing - they originated so you could stand in the stirrup of a galloping horse.

Comment: That is both terrifying and amazing.

Comment: I noticed that this view is excellent! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Astronaut_Scott_Parazynski_repairs_a_damaged_ISS_solar_panel.jpg especially if cropped below a width of 640 pixels https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Coe.jpg

Comment: Nice one with the EVA guy on the end of the inspection boom.

Comment: I've just asked [What is the purpose of this cable connecting Astronaut's boot restraint to a robotic arm?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27982/12102)

Comment: Joining the party two years after the fact, but I'm very curious to know why, in the 3rd photo, there is a Western Union logo inside the Shuttle bay? Given that we're probably still a century away from having a Western Union office in Earth orbit.

Comment: @clayRay why not ask that as a question, rather than in a comment?

Comment: @clayRay I'm pretty sure its there to make sure I get the song by The Five Americans stuck in my head, two years later!

Comment: @OrganicMarble I was just about to do that but then I found the answer: Western Union owned a majority stake in all the Westar Satellites. This is presumably the retrieval mission for the failed Westar 6.

Comment: @clayRay actually that's mission 41-b which launched Westar 6.  Here's a similar picture with the details. https://images.nasa.gov/details-S84-27021

Comment: Aha @OrganicMarble - then it makes more sense that Western Union would want to have their name up in the bay